# How could I calculate the percentage of total in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, subquery

I'm using postgreSQL to create a query that be able to calculates the percentage of total based on a category (column "modelo_venta") and also has other different columns, I've made a try as follow but it's not working well and i'm not getting the 100% when I summarize the percentages:

```
SELECT
    pais,
    estatus,
    centro,
    drv,
    uen,
    agencia,
    modelo_venta,
    Sum(fuera_ruta_volumen_cartones) as fuera_ruta_volumen_cartones,
    Sum(fuera_ruta_volumen_hectolitros) as fuera_ruta_volumen_hectolitros,
    round(cast(count(modelo_venta) * 100.0 / (select count(*) FROM reporting_services.vw_mx_log_icaro_modelo_servicio_fuera_ruta) as numeric),3) as porcentaje,
    fecha_reparto
FROM
    reporting_services.vw_mx_log_icaro_modelo_servicio_fuera_ruta
WHERE
    modelo_venta IS NOT NULL
    and motivo_fuera_ruta = 'Otros Motivos'
group by
    pais,
    estatus,
    centro,
    drv
    uen,
    agencia,
    modelo_venta,
    fuera_ruta_volumen_cartones,
    fuera_ruta_volumen_hectolitros,
    fecha_reparto
ORDER BY
    porcentaje DESC
```

The output is somenthing like this:

| modelo_ventas | porcentaje |
| --- | --- |
| A | .0002 |
| B | .10 |
| C | .10 |
| D | .003 |

The desired output would be something like:

| modelo_ventas | porcentaje |
| --- | --- |
| A | 40 |
| B | 40 |
| C | 10 |
| D | 10 |

Do you know what is wrong here, guys? thanks by the way, best regards.

Comment: also include your sample data for given ouyput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using window functions:

```
count(modelo_venta) * 100.0 / sum(count(modelo_venta)) over () as porcentaje,
```

The issue is that you want to count based on the results of the query, not the entire table.

Comment: Hi Gordon! thanks a lot for sharing this with me, Nevertheless is not working, when I use your try it returns me near 64% in total and not the 100% do you know if i'm missing something? basically im using the same as you

Comment: @Xkid . . . It should return 100% -- by definition.  I fixed the logic though to count `modelo_venta`.  Now it should add up to 100%.

Comment: I changed it as you and it returned the same value (62) I don't know but maybe something is wrong with my "group by" logic

Comment: @Xkid . . . Somehow some rows are getting filtered out.  Perhaps you are not looking at all the rows in the result set?

Comment: Yes! this was happening I was filtering a category now I've 100% thanks a lot!